# How to use react-data-table-component to display array stored in the constructor this:state?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to the React, And I want to using react-data-table-component to display my fetch data from Api in a sorted table. but the issue I do not know the correct method to use the react-data-table-component.and the instruction of react-data-table-component do not include such example.

Following is my code:

I was trying to put offence or this.state.offence direct into data, but show nothing, anyone please give me some advises about the correct way to use this or some other way create sorted table to show this data.and there is link to the react-data-table-component [a link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { off } from 'rsvp';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';



const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Offences',
    selector: 'Offences',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Year',
    selector: 'year',
    sortable: true,
    right: true,
  },
];

class SignInForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            offence:[],
            
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleClick =this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleLogin =this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    }
handleClick(){
      const url ="https://xxxxxxxxxx.sh/offences";
       fetch(url)
       .then(response => {
         console.log(response.clone().json())
         console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.clone().json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
        }
      })
      .then((res) =>{ 
        console.log(res)
    
        
        this.setState({
          offence: [res]
           });
        
        
      }) // get just the list of articles
      console.log(this.state.offence);
      
    }
render() {
        return (
          
                  <button className="FormField__offence" onClick{this.handleClick}>offence</button>
                 
                  
              </div>
              
              <div> 
              <DataTable
        title="Offences"
        columns={columns}
        data={this.state.offence}
      />
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
 
           
        );
        
    }
}


export default SignInForm;
```

I was expecting one column decent table show

Comment: Is your onClick event getting execute?

Comment: I can see a space missing here <button className="FormField__offence"onClick{this.handleClick}>offence</button> before onClick event

Comment: yes, I forget to mention is should be when the offence button clicked, the table should show, that space is not missing in my code , i guess it is because it's because I am not familiar with stack overflow, so the code paste made some different

Comment: So, in this case is your console.log(this.state.offence); statement prints correct data? And try to print it in render() method.

Comment: actual ..no it is empty and like this[] i have no ideal why, but i try print it in the render() {
      console.log(this.state.offence)
        return (     this one is working and show me the data array

Comment: post your console.log(this.state.offence)  output

Comment: just, updta, the first click offence , everything like my previous comment, but after the second click, the two console.(this.state.offence) all show the array i need, but still nothing in the table..

Comment: paste your console output here

Comment: could you simply post your output of `console.log(this.state.offence)` here bro @Norman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const columns = [
      {
        name: 'Offences',
        selector: 'Offences',
        sortable: true,
      }
    ];
    
    class SignInForm extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
    
        this.state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          offence: [],
    
        };
    
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
    
      handleClick() {
        const url = "https://xxxxxxxx.sh/offences";
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.clone().json();
            } else {
              throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
            }
          })
          .then((res) => {
    
            this.setState({
              offence: res.offences.map((item,id) => ({id, Offences: item}))
            });
    
    
          }) // get just the list of articles
      }
    
      render() {
          console.log(this.state.offence)
    
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <button
            className="FormField__offence"
            onClick={this.handleClick}>offence</button>
    
            <DataTable
              title="Offences"
              columns={columns}
              data={this.state.offence}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

[Live Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/32239x6rw6)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

```
this.setState({
  offence: [res]
});
```

with this,

```
this.setState({
  offence: res
});
```

In your case this is `res` from API call

```
{offences: Array(88)}
offences: (88) ["Advertising Prostitution", ... "Weapons Act Offences", "Weapons Act Offences - Other"]
__proto__: Object
```

So you can get offences like this,

```
this.setState({
      offence: res.offences
});
```

Comment: emmm still nothing, but console show warning:index.js:1446 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `r`, expected `array`.at first click

Comment: this one always works fine. console.log(res) show result same as console.log(this.state.offence)

Comment: I do but it says something went wrong and Error:Cannot read property 'map' of null, Abdullah's method is work prefect.